# MultipleObjectsReturned display when form is submitted

Tags: django

i have a model with FileField, when i submit a form uploading images it submits for the first time. But when i want to upload another image i get this error: get() returned more than one Image -- it returned 2!

```
class Image(models.Model):
    imageuploader_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    first_upload_image = models.FileField(upload_to ='pictsagram/',null=True)
    second_upload_image = models.FileField(upload_to ='pictsagram/',null=True)

def home(request):
    all_images = Image.objects.filter(imageuploader_profile=request.user.id)
    try:
        upload_images = Image.objects.get(imageuploader_profile=request.user.id)
    except Image.DoesNotExist:
        upload_images = None

    all_users = Profile.objects.all()
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    if next: return redirect(next)
    context = {
        'all_images': all_images,
        'all_users': all_users,
        'upload_images': upload_images,
    }
    return render(request,'home.html', context,)

def upload(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.imageuploader_profile = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {"form": form})

{% if upload_images.first_upload_image %}
      <img src="{{ upload_images.first_upload_image.url }}" class="img-fluid d-block w-100" alt="orange tree" />
      {% endif %}
{% if upload_images.second_upload_image %}
          <img src="{{ upload_images.second_upload_image.url }}" class="img-fluid d-block w-100" alt="orange tree" />
          {% endif %}
```

Comment: It means that your query `Image.objects.get(imageuploader_profile=request.user.id)` returns *multiple* images, so not one, but for example two.

Comment: @Willem i also thought about that but i do not know how to pass this error

Comment: If I use upload_images = Image objects.filter('all field' :...). When I upload an image it display no attribute file for second_upload_image. This is my template. {% if upload_images.first_upload_image %} {{ upload_images.first_upload_image}} {% endif %} {% if upload_images.second_upload_image %} {{ upload_images.second_upload_image}} {% endif %}

Comment: you need to *iterate* over the `upload_images`.

Comment: @Willem How do I do that, please help with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `modelname.objects.get("field_name"="**")`
It will always give you a single object that matches your query. 
If your database contains more than one objects that matches your query you should use **filter**

```
modelname.objects.filter("field_name"="**")
```

Comment: If I use upload_images = Image objects.filter('all field' :...). When I upload an image it display no attribute file for second_upload_image. This is my template. {% if upload_images.first_upload_image %} {{ upload_images.first_upload_image}} {% endif %} {% if upload_images.second_upload_image %} {{ upload_images.second_upload_image}} {% endif %}

Comment: Can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157046/saving-data-to-admin-using-form

Answer (score 0):

This happens because every time when you submit the form you write a new record in the database instead of updating the current one.

Assuming that **imageuploader_profile** can only have one row in the table

```
def upload(request):

    upload_images = Image.objects.filter(imageuploader_profile=request.user.id).first()

    form = PostForm(instance=upload_images)

    if request.method == "POST":

        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=upload_images)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.imageuploader_profile = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {"form": form})
```

Comment: thank you, how do i display the filefield (images) i uploaded with the form on templates.

Comment: If I use upload_images = Image objects.filter('all field' :...). When I upload an image it display no attribute file for second_upload_image. This is my template. {% if upload_images.first_upload_image %} {{ upload_images.first_upload_image}} {% endif %} {% if upload_images.second_upload_image %} {{ upload_images.second_upload_image}} {% endif %}